# Java application, linking model, view and controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, solid-principles

I'm going to write a program which is like a 'User Management' system for administrators with a command-line view. The requirements are logging in and out, user permissions (and only those with admin permissions can log on), add users, remove users, delete users, ban users temporarily, view user requests which can be outstanding, in progress or completed and will be assigned to an admin. (I'm not worrying about creating a user request. Users who do not have admin permissions are able to create requests through another application that will be made later).

This is just for learning, it's not a system that will actually be used in real life. It's to practice MVC, and good practice with the SOLID principles.

I'm going to use MVC. I understand what the model, view and controller are supposed to do individually but I'm not sure how to go about putting it together.

When the static main method runs, where should it go from here? To a controller? Is it okay for it to call the view first?

The way I'm thinking is to have the main method call a method in the view which prints out the options (i.e. press 1 to login, 2 to exit). Then depending on the option chosen by the user, it goes to a method in the relevant controller. But then, the view would be dependent on all of the controllers - I don't know if this is bad practice or not? Because then the view is responsible for calling other things, but this should be the controller's job right?

If the main method calls the controller first, I guess I'd have to have some sort of super controller to kick everything off?

E.g.
Main method calls handle in supercontroller
which calls mainMenu in view, which returns the chosen option
If the returned option is login, supercontroller's handle then calls logincontroller's login method?

Appreciate any help or guidance with this.

Answer (score 0):

When building a UI with MVC, you first call the controller. The controller is the only one in the game who knows/sees everything. So the controller then creates a view, initializes the view, possibly even creates a model, attaches the model to the view and sets up everything that the view works.

While the user enters data, the controller is invoked (or rather methods on the controller) which update the model and possibly change the view.

Parent controllers can be used to build complex systems from more simple MVC components.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you call the `main` method - it should call the controller method. Which controller method to call depends on your application logic, i.e. what is the first action when user accesses your application for the first time. In MVC pattern controllers are responsible to decide which view to show, so the main point of entry should be the controller.